# subprocess.Popen help needed

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipc

I need to execute a command using `subprocess.Popen`. 
The command which I need to run is:

```
./Test -t -1
```

Test is an executable file while the other arguments `-t` and `-1` are for enabling the outputs (logs) to the shell. I want to write the output to a log file.

Unfortunately I am unable to do it.

I tried like this:

```
output = open("outputlog.log", "a")
subprocess.Popen(["./Test", "-t", "-1"], stdout = output)
```

Please help me in this regard.

Regards
Tamoor

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
output = open("outputlog.log", "a")
p = subprocess.Popen(["./Test", "-t", "-1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output.writelines(p.stdout.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things might be going wrong:

1. `Test -t -1` may be writing to stderr, not stdout.
2. `output` may need to be flushed or closed before the buffer is
   written to disk.

Try:

```
with open("outputlog.log", "a") as output:
    subprocess.Popen(["./Test", "-t", "-1"], stdout=output, stderr=output)
```

This will write both stdout and stderr to `output`, and close (and flush) `output` when the `with`-suite ends.